# Ajax ReordeList and asp:FileUpload Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ajax

I have a ReorderList which is working fine, inside the InsertItemTemplate, I've added a asp:Fileupload to add images to the list and database. All of these controls are inside a DIV.

How could I reach to this (asp:FileUpload) in C# to check whether it has a file or not,

this is the C# part of the code:

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    string sFilename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();



    FileUpload filePhoto = (FileUpload)div1.FindControl("filePhoto");



    if (filePhoto.HasFile)

    {

        string sPath = "";

        string sFile = filePhoto.FileName.ToString();

        sPath = Server.MapPath("Images");

        filePhoto.SaveAs(sPath + "\\" + sFile);



        //to fill the Notice image by code behine

        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["theImage"].DefaultValue = "Images\\" + sFile;

    }

    else

    {

        //to fill the Notice image by code behine

        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["theImage"].DefaultValue = "Images\\" + "NoImage.jpg";

    }





}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually ReorderList is an ajax control and you cannot use normal Asp:Fileuploader in ajax control. You have to use the asyncfileuploader control of ajax control toolkit in order to work in ajax application.